# How to check if user was already with that property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this example array:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bob",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "John",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Bob",
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Bob",
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Bob",
    }
]
```

In this array I want to add a property color to each object from array with an Loop, but if User already has that property color assigned don't add any other color KEEP the first one assigned.

What it looks like now is adding random color to user, and can't check if user have color RED already and doesn't need another one (needs to KEEP the FIRST ONE - RED)

What I need to achieve is:
Whenever the user exists - add ONLY ONE color to it, and for other users same thing UNIQUE color for EACH USER in part.

```js
const myArr = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bob",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "John",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Bob",
    },
    {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Bob",
    },
    {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Bob",
    }
];

for (var i = 0, len = myArr.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var colors = ["#A43548", "#35A4A0", "#55B747", "#1F85DE"];
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * colors.length))
    
    var checker = myArr.hasOwnProperty("avatarcolor")

    if(checker == false) {
      myArr[i].avatarcolor = colors[random]; // add color
    } else {
      console.log(`Already we have color to that user!`)
    }
}

console.log(myArr)
```

Comment: Change `myArr[b]` to `myArr[i]`

Comment: And `myArr.hasOwnProperty("avatarcolor")` to `myArr[i].hasOwnProperty("avatarcolor")`

Comment: The sample data needs at least one element with avatarcolor assigned.

Comment: @gillall Why? I can't achieve to add unique color to an user without?

Comment: "but if User already has that property color assigned don't add any other color KEEP the first one assigned."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Idea is when Loop assigned color RED to Bob, I don't want to assign
> any more colors to it ONLY that color RED

Use array `reduce` & inside callback check use `find`. In `find` callback check if there exist an array where name matches and it also have the property. `find` will return `undefined` if it does not find that object. In that case add the new property to the object

```js
const myArr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Bob"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "John"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Bob"
  }
];

var colors = ["#A43548", "#35A4A0", "#55B747", "#1F85DE"];
myArr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const x = acc.find(
    item => item.name === curr.name && item.hasOwnProperty("avatarcolor")
  );
  if (!x) {
    curr["avatarcolor"] = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  } else {
    curr["avatarcolor"] = x.avatarcolor;
  }
  acc.push(curr);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: Idea is when Loop assigned color RED to Bob, I don't want to assign any more colors to it ONLY that color RED, and same for other names.

Comment: Color can be added one time with this code: myArr[i].avatarcolor = myArr[i].avatarcolor ||  colors[random]

Comment: @brk Thanks, It's close but if user have already color RED for example, add color RED not to be empty or other color.